# SQL - Mostrar os 10 maiores valores por mês

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de mostrar na tela os 10 maiores valores de doação de cada mês do ano de 2018 da tabela `Doacao`.

Meu banco é o SQL SERVER.
Por enquanto tenho a seguinte query:

```
select
    datename(month,doacao.Doacao_sdt_Data) as Mes,
    pessoa.Nome_Completo, 
    doacao.valor as valor_doacao,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10),doacao.Data, 103) as data_doacao
from doacao
inner join pessoa on (doacao.codigo = pessoa.codigo)
where year(doacao.Data) = 2018
order by month(doacao.Data), doacao.valor desc
```

Com essa query vejo todas as doações de cada mês, e se eu colocar um top(10) no inicio, aparece apenas as 10 primeiras de janeiro:

Abaixo imagens do resultado SEM e COM o Top:

[image: Resultado SEM o TOP]

Resultado com o TOP:

[image: Resultado com o TOP]

Comment: Primeiro, você precisa definir se o seu banco de dados é MySql ou Oracle.

Comment: Meu banco de dados é SQL SERVER.

Comment: (1) Qual a diferença entre as colunas `Doacao_sdt_Data` e `Data`? (2) Como está declarada a coluna `Doacao_sdt_Data`? (3) Se a coluna `Doacao_sdt_Data` estiver declarada como _datetime_, ela contém data e hora ou somente data?

Comment: este nome esta errado Doacao_sdt_Data  o correto é o data realmente,

Comment: @JoséDiz Tentei executar, mas da erro nessa linha:                              
   "seq= dense_rank over (partition by year ([Data]), month ([Data]) '

                                                                                                            
   ------>>> ERRO:  >>>  

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.

Comment: Consegui resolver o erro. Funcionou. Obrigado. @JoséDiz

Comment: @c3s1 Fui verificar o erro e estava `dense_rank` quando o correto é `dense_rank()`. Já corrigi também no código.

Comment: Exatamente isso que fiz, dense_rank()   Deu Certo!!  Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avalie a seguinte sugestão, que considera que a coluna `Data` está declarada como `date`.

```
-- código #1 v3
-- informe ano a consultar
declare @Ano smallint;
set @Ano= 2018;

-- variáveis de período anual (garante sargability)
declare @De date, @Ate date;
set dateformat dmy;
set @De= cast ('1/1/' + cast (@Ano as char(4)) as date);
set @Ate= cast ('31/12/' + cast (@Ano as char(4)) as date);

--
set language brazilian;

with doacao_seq as (
SELECT *,
       seq= dense_rank() over (partition by year ([Data]), month ([Data])
                             order by valor desc)
  from doacao
  where [Data] between @De and @Ate
)
SELECT datename (month, D.Data) as Mes,
       P.Nome_Completo, 
       D.valor as valor_doacao,
       convert (char(10), D.Data, 103) as data_doacao
  from doacao_seq as D
       inner join pessoa as P on (D.codigo = P.codigo)
  where D.seq <= 10
  order by month(D.Data), D.seq;
```

Observe que foram criadas 2 variáveis, @De e @Ate, para conter o período de seleção. O motivo está descrito no artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)”.

Além da função [dense_rank()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql), há também a função [rank()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql). Há uma sutil diferença entre elas; deve-se avaliar qual delas deve ser utilizada para obter o relatório. No artigo “[Funções de janela (*window functions*)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/funcoes-de-janela-window-functions/)” há explicação de funcionamento destas duas funções de janela.